# Watir / Ruby: How to get the text of the selected item in a drop down list?

Tags: ruby, watir

Using Watir, how can I return the text of the currently selected item in a drop down list?  It appears that getSelectedItems is deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use selected_options() instead.

> selected_options ()
>       Description:
>
> Gets all the selected items in the select list as an array.
>       An empty array is returned if the select box has no selected item.
>       Output:
>
> Array containing the selected items of the select list.

[Source](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/classes/FireWatir/SelectList.html#M000244)

Comment: Thank you... I don't know how I didn't see that!

Comment: I'm using Watir-Webdriver and I'm getting this: [#<Watir::Option:0x1d07556be located=true selector={:element=>(webdriver element)}>]. It would really be nice to get the text. Any help?

Comment: @blizzyb I am getting the same problem without seeming able to find a workaround via other methods or attributes...

Comment: @blizzyb, use select_element.selected_options.first.text

Answer (score 2):

The watir documentation also says you can do

```
browser.select_list.selected_options.map(&:text)
```

but this returns the text in an array, I guess it would be useful to do it this way if you have multiple items selected in the list.

```
['selected text']
```

Comment: If you only have one element selected, `browser.select_list.selected_options.map(&:text)[0]` would give you the selected text as a string.

Comment: And something like `browser.select_list(:id,'list_id').selected_options.map(&:text)[0]` may prove useful in locating the list itself.